# How to send data as key/value to Kafka using Apache Flink with Specific Partitioner

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a payload in Flink like below;

```
{
    "memberId": 4
    "total": 5
}
```

I want to send data to kafka as key-value format with specified partitioner. For partitioner, i'll use Modulo partitioner.

An example for modulo partitioner;

`partitionId = value % numPartitions`

Let's assume `numPartitions` parameter is 3. If we can use memberId of the payload defined above, partitionId should be `4 % 3` = 1

According to the above partitioner, I want to send data that have the same partitionId to the same kafka topic. Another examples;

If(assume numPartitions = 3);

```
memberId: 3 => (3 % 3) => partitionId = 0 => kafka partition 1
memberId: 8 => (8 % 3) => partitionId = 2 => kafka partition 2
memberId: 2 => (2 % 3) => partitionId = 2 => kafka partition 2
memberId: 6 => (6 % 3) => partitionId = 0 => kafka partition 1
memberId: 7 => (7 % 3) => partitionId = 1 => kafka partition 2
```

If I'm not wrong, flink kafka producer uses FlinkFixedPartitioner if we can not specify any key and partition function. If we set partition function as `null`, flink kafka producer will use round robin distribution. But i don't know how can i send data to kafka as key/value format, how can i partition it by modulo. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `KafkaSerializationSchema`, then you can create Kafka `ProducerRecords`, and set the Kafka key (and value). You can also set the partition in the `ProducerRecord`.

Comment: So, what about the modulo partitioner?

Comment: Ohh thank you! ProducerRecord can be take kafka partition!